MLflow pip install error: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mlflow==2.8.1" during mlflow run command
I have just set up a project by cloning the original repo and following the instructions. However, when I run the command to download data using MLflow, I encounter a pip installation error.
Command run:
mlflow run . -P steps=download
The error output:
(nyc_airbnb_dev) nhan@PC:~/workspace/build-ml-pipeline-for-short-term-rental-prices$ mlflow run . -P steps=download
2024/09/11 20:16:37 INFO mlflow.utils.conda: === Creating conda environment mlflow-498808f8c125fa02022e7f09f7b0b2b49dc0ce8a ===
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
Installing pip dependencies: ...working... Pip subprocess error:
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2309353610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/mlflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2309353460>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/mlflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2309353a00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/mlflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f230937c9a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/mlflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f230937cb50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/mlflow/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mlflow==2.8.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mlflow==2.8.1
failed
CondaEnvException: Pip failed
2024/09/11 20:17:33 WARNING mlflow.utils.conda: Encountered unexpected error while creating conda environment. Removing mlflow-498808f8c125fa02022e7f09f7b0b2b49dc0ce8a.
Remove all packages in environment /home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/mlflow-498808f8c125fa02022e7f09f7b0b2b49dc0ce8a:
## Package Plan ##
  environment location: /home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/mlflow-498808f8c125fa02022e7f09f7b0b2b49dc0ce8a
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  _libgcc_mutex-0.1-conda_forge
  _openmp_mutex-4.5-2_gnu
  antlr-python-runtime-4.9.3-pyhd8ed1ab_1
  bzip2-1.0.8-h4bc722e_7
  ca-certificates-2024.8.30-hbcca054_0
  hydra-core-1.3.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  importlib_resources-6.4.5-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  ld_impl_linux-64-2.40-hf3520f5_7
  libffi-3.4.2-h7f98852_5
  libgcc-14.1.0-h77fa898_1
  libgcc-ng-14.1.0-h69a702a_1
  libgomp-14.1.0-h77fa898_1
  libnsl-2.0.1-hd590300_0
  libsqlite-3.46.1-hadc24fc_0
  libuuid-2.38.1-h0b41bf4_0
  libxcrypt-4.4.36-hd590300_1
  libzlib-1.3.1-h4ab18f5_1
  ncurses-6.5-he02047a_1
  omegaconf-2.3.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  openssl-3.3.2-hb9d3cd8_0
  packaging-24.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pip-23.3.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  python-3.10.14-hd12c33a_0_cpython
  python_abi-3.10-5_cp310
  pyyaml-6.0.2-py310ha75aee5_1
  readline-8.2-h8228510_1
  setuptools-73.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  tk-8.6.13-noxft_h4845f30_101
  typing_extensions-4.12.2-pyha770c72_0
  tzdata-2024a-h8827d51_1
  wheel-0.44.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  xz-5.2.6-h166bdaf_0
  yaml-0.2.5-h7f98852_2
  zipp-3.20.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/bin/mlflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/cli.py", line 204, in run
    projects.run(
  File "/home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/projects/__init__.py", line 337, in run
    submitted_run_obj = _run(
  File "/home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/projects/__init__.py", line 106, in _run
    submitted_run = backend.run(
  File "/home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/projects/backend/local.py", line 171, in run
    conda_env = get_or_create_conda_env(project.env_config_path)
  File "/home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/conda.py", line 269, in get_or_create_conda_env
    return _create_conda_env_func(
  File "/home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/conda.py", line 108, in _create_conda_env
    process._exec_cmd(
  File "/home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/process.py", line 117, in _exec_cmd
    raise ShellCommandException.from_completed_process(comp_process)
mlflow.utils.process.ShellCommandException: Non-zero exit code: 1
Command: ['/home/nhan/miniconda3/bin/conda', 'env', 'create', '-n', 'mlflow-498808f8c125fa02022e7f09f7b0b2b49dc0ce8a', '--file', '/home/nhan/workspace/build-ml-pipeline-for-short-term-rental-prices/conda.yml', '--quiet']

Here are the details of my MLflow installation:
$ pip show mlflow
Name: mlflow
Version: 2.8.1
Location: /home/nhan/miniconda3/envs/nyc_airbnb_dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages

’ve been trying to solve this issue for a week but haven’t had any success. It seems like the issue might be related to pip failing to connect or find the required package. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?
Additional Details:
OS: Linux
MLflow version: 2.8.1
Python version: 3.10
Conda is being used to manage environments
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!
I have tried checking the internet connection, DNS, etc., but I still can't run this command.
